# tkinter - How to get which menu item caused callback?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, callback

I would like to have a single callback function for my menu.  In order to determine what action to take in the callback, I need to know which menu item generated the callback. I have been unable to figure this out.

I see an option called "variable" in the add call, but when I try to use it I get an error.  I thought perhaps it would allow me to specify a StringVar that the menu text would be stored in.

Would like to know in the hello function who generated the callback.  Is it possible to specify a parameter that can be passed in?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def hello():
    print ("hello!")

# create a toplevel menu
menubar = Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Hello!", command=hello)
menubar.add_command(label="Quit!", command=hello)

# display the menu
root.config(menu=menubar)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Upon further research, it appears the way to do this is using lamba for the command.... command = lambda:hello('Hello!')  would be one way of passing in a string representing the menu item.  I think this is the way to do it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, avoid star imports. You can import it will other name to make it less typical.

```
import tkinter as tk
```

`command` on menu don't return anything. You can use `lambda` or make separate functions.

### Using [`lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp):

```
root = tk.Tk()

# create a toplevel menu
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Hello!", command=lambda:print("Hello!"))
menubar.add_command(label="Quit!", command=lambda:print("hello!"))

# display the menu
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

When you press the `Hello!` menu, it will print `Hello!` but when you press `Quit!` then it prints `hello!`

### Using separate functions:

```
root = tk.Tk()
def hello():   #Hello! menu
    print("hello!")
def Hello():   #Quit! menu
    print("Hello!")
# create a toplevel menu
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Hello!", command=hello)
menubar.add_command(label="Quit!", command=Hello)

# display the menu
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

You can make separate functions to identify the menu callback.

### Making 3 functions:

You can make 3 functions. One will be the main which you will be calling in the other two functions. It will give you a benefit to identify the menu. Here is an example:

```
root = tk.Tk()
def _main():
    print("hello!")
def hello():   #Hello! menu
    _main()
def Hello():   #Quit! menu
    _main()

# create a toplevel menu
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Hello!", command=hello)
menubar.add_command(label="Quit!", command=Hello)

# display the menu
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I wouldn't use import * in my own code. This was sample code that I copied that illustrated what I was looking for.

Comment: @MikeyB Caring is good. I hope that `Making 3 functions` will help you for what you are looking.

Comment: I appreciate the work that must have taken!  Thanks for putting it together.

Answer (score 1):

The question posted was:

> Would like to know in the hello function who generated the callback.
>   Is it possible to specify a parameter that can be passed in?

After a bit of research I found out how for my function to know who called it.  It was trickier code than I expected.

The line of code that I use is:

```
    top_menu.add_command(label=sub_menu_info, command=lambda: Menu.MenuItemChosenCallback(element, sub_menu_info))
```

I've not used lambda before so they syntax was throwing me.  I have a method in my "Menu" class named MeduItemChosenCallback.  It is declared as this:

def MenuItemChosenCallback(self, item_chosen):

I didn't realize I needed to put the class name on the function in the lambda.  I thought it would have been `element.MenuItemChosenCallback` as that's variable is a Menu object.  Again, not used lambda before so needed to work through the syntax.

Using the sample code originally posted, determining who made the call to `hello` was done with a parameter:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def hello(parm):
    print (parm)

# create a toplevel menu
menubar = Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Hello!", command= lambda: hello('1'))
menubar.add_command(label="Quit!", command=lambda: hello('2'))


# display the menu
root.config(menu=menubar)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, the best solution is for each command to call a different function.

```
menubar.add_command(label="Hello!", command=menu_hello)
menubar.add_command(label="Quit!", command=menu_quit)
```

If you feel the need to have more than one menu item call the same command, using `lambda` or [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is typically what is used:

Example:

```
menubar.add_command(label="Hello!", command=lambda: hello("1"))
menubar.add_command(label="Quit!", command=lambda: hello("2"))
```